# Android - clip ViewGroups children on one of many drawables area

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas

I'm now working with some custom views on Android App, and now I'm facing problem that I have no idea how to solve. I draw views borders using background drawables and paddings for drawables(not views). For example typical FrameLayout looks like that:

[image]

But my problem starts when in ViewGroups children should been clipped for blue area, but they are drawn like that:

[image]

My point is to achive situation when green area(child of any kind) will be clipped to blue area, also including radiuses etc.

I've tried clipToPadding() and Canvas.clipPath() but ended up with nothing.

Any one had similar situation and could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found simple solution, I changed my onDraw method do similar like:

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    getBackground().draw(canvas);
    mPath.reset();
    getDrawingRect(tmpRect);

    if (mRoundRect.left != tmpRect.left || mRoundRect.right != tmpRect.right ||
            mRoundRect.top != tmpRect.top || mRoundRect.bottom != tmpRect.bottom) {
        mRoundRect.set(tmpRect.left+border, tmpRect.top+border, tmpRect.right-border, tmpRect.bottom-border);
        mPath.addRoundRect(mRoundRect, floatsRadiuses, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(mPath);
    }

    int childrenSize = getChildCount();
    for(int i=0;i<childrenSize;i++){
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        drawChild(canvas,child,getDrawingTime());
    }


}
```